# scipy: how to get the number of not all-zero rows

Tags: scipy

I am using `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` to present the parse matrix. The purpose is to determine how many rows are not all zero. For example:

```
M = [[0,0,0],
     [0,1,0],
     [1,1,0]]
```

is 2 because two rows `M[1]` and `M[2]` are not all-zero. What is the probably best way to do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by _best_? Is it in terms of efficiency, or style or conciseness of the solution, etc. Might help come up with a more precise answer to your question.

Comment: So sorry for the ambiguity. I specify the condition: the dtype is np.bool, and the best here we consider the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing this is the following:

```
(M.sum(axis=1) > 0).sum()
```

This sums elements along each row and counts the number of non-zero items in the resulting vector.

EDIT:

Here's an alternative solution that does not sum any of the elements of the matrix, and relies on native `scipy` and Python functionality:

`len(set(mat.nonzero()[0]))`

Comment: Thanks for your attention. That is a practical solution, wonder if there are more efficient way since no need to calculate the sum of each row.

Comment: Note that if M can contain negative values, this method might return an incorrect result.

Comment: Good point @WarrenWeckesser. I just noted that OP clarified that the `dtype` is bool, so this should be OK.

Comment: How about this @tianxingwang: `len(set(mat.nonzero()[0]))`. You first get the row and column indices of non-zero elements, then you select just the row indices, get their unique values and count them. No addition, no looping other than what goes on internal to `scipy` and the native Python `set` and `len` functions. I've updated the solution as well.

Comment: Nice, seems more efficient.